# Sum of a series $\frac {1}{n^2 - m^2}$ m and n odd, $m \ne n$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, summation, closed-form

I was working on a physics problem, where I encountered the following summation problem:
$$ \sum_{m = 1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2 - m^2}$$ where m doesn't equal n, and both are odd. n is a fixed constant

We could alternatively write:
$$ \sum_{j = 1}^\infty \frac{1}{(2i - 1)^2 - (2j - 1)^2}$$ where i doesn't equal j. I used a numerical solver to solve for a few values of n, and the solution seems to be $-1/(4n^2)$ which fits with the problem, but I'd like to find a rigorous solution.

My attempts so far have involved simplifying the term in the sum in various was to see if I could find a way solve the problem, but I've had no luck.

Ex. The second equation can be simplified to
$$\sum_{j=1}^\infty \frac {1} {4(i + j - 1)(i - j)} $$
but I'm not sure where to go from here.

I've also tried splitting the problem into two sections, one where m < n, and one where m > n, but again, I'm not sure how to continue.

Comment: I would try partial fractions on $\frac{1}{(n-m)(n+m)}$ and hope for a telescope.

Comment: Use the identity 
$$\frac{\sin \pi n}{\pi n}=\prod_{m=1}^\infty\left(1-\frac{n^2}{m^2}\right).$$
Take logarithm and then derivative from both sides and see what happens for odd $n$.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio, he restricts $m$ to be unequal to $n$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume $N>i\geq1$. Starting by a partial fraction decomposition, one may write
$$
\begin{align}
&\sum_{j=1,\,j\neq i}^N\frac1{(2i-1)^2-(2j-1)^2}
\\\\&=\frac1{4(2i-1)}\sum_{j=1,\,j\neq i}^N\left(\frac1{j+i-1}-\frac1{j-i}\right)
\\\\&=\frac1{4(2i-1)}\left(\sum_{j=1}^N\frac1{j+i-1}-\frac1{2i-1}-\sum_{j=1,\,j\neq i}^N\frac1{j-i}\right)
\\\\&=\frac1{4(2i-1)}\left(\sum_{\ell=i}^{N+i-1}\frac1{\ell}-\frac1{2i-1}-\sum_{j=1}^{i-1}\frac1{j-i}-\sum_{j=i+1}^N\frac1{j-i}\right)
\\\\&=\frac1{4(2i-1)}\left(H_{N+i-1}-H_{i-1}-\frac1{2i-1}+H_{i-1}-H_{N-i}\right)
\\\\&=-\frac1{4(2i-1)^2}+\frac1{4(2i-1)}\left(H_{N+i-1}-H_{N-i}\right)
\end{align}
$$ then, as $N \to \infty$,

> $$
> \sum_{j=1,\,j\neq i}^\infty\frac1{(2i-1)^2-(2j-1)^2}=-\frac1{4(2i-1)^2}
> $$

where $H_N$ is the harmonic number and where we have used
$$
H_{N+i-1}-H_{N-i}=O\left(\frac1{N}\right)
$$ as $N \to \infty$.

Comment: Can you post a link to an explanation for why $H_{N+i-1} - H_{N-i} = O(\frac 1 N)$?

Comment: @Zar One may recall that $\lim_{n \to \infty}H_n-\log n=\gamma$, the Euler constant, thus you may write, as $N \to \infty$ $\displaystyle  H_{N+i-1}-H_{N-i}=\left(H_{N+i-1}-\log (N+i-1)\right)-\left(H_{N-i}-\log (N-i)\right)+\log ((N+i-1)/(N-i))$.

Comment: @Zar Observe that, since $\log (1+x) \sim x$ as $x \to 0$, then $\log ((N+i-1)/(N-i)) = \log (1+(2i-1)/(N-i))\sim O(1/N)$. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If we start with:
$$ \cos\left(\frac{\pi x}{2}\right) = \prod_{k\geq 0}\left(1-\frac{x^2}{(2k+1)^2}\right) $$
we get, by considering the logarithmic derivative:
$$ \frac{\pi}{4x}\cdot\tan\left(\frac{\pi x}{2}\right) = \sum_{k\geq 0}\frac{1}{(1+2k)^2-x^2}$$
that is a meromorphic function with a regular point in the origin and simple poles at the odd integers: the residue at $x=\pm(2K+1)$ is just $\mp\frac{1}{4K+2}$. We also have:
$$\begin{eqnarray*} \sum_{\substack{k\geq 0 \\ k\neq K}}\frac{1}{(2k+1)^2-(2K+1)^2} &=& \lim_{x\to(2K+1)}\left(\frac{\pi}{4x}\cdot\tan\left(\frac{\pi x}{2}\right)-\frac{1}{(2K+1)^2-x^2}\right)\\&=&\lim_{x\to(2K+1)}\left(\frac{\pi}{4x}\cdot\tan\left(\frac{\pi x}{2}\right)-\frac{\frac{1}{4K+2}}{(2K+1)-x}-\frac{\frac{1}{4K+2}}{(2K+1)+x}\right)\\&=&\color{red}{-\frac{1}{(4K+2)^2}}\end{eqnarray*}$$
since we know in advance what the singular part at $x=2K+1$ is.

Comment: You could also have used the infinite sereis for $\sin$ as I proposed in my comment to the original post.

Comment: @Luckyluck63: sure, but I thought the cosine was more suited for accounting the odd-ness of the involved integers. The same approach with the cosine function replaced with a sine function leads to the computation of $$\sum_{\substack{m\geq 1\\m\neq n}}\frac{1}{n^2-m^2}.$$

Comment: Great, thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 0):

The case of all integers is
$$
\sum_{m=1}^{n-1}\frac{1}{n^2-m^2}+\sum_{m=n+1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^2-m^2} = \frac{-3}{4n^2}
$$
and the "odd" case is similar
$$
\sum_{k=1}^{j-1}\frac{1}{(2j-1)^2-(2k-1)^2}
+\sum_{k=j+1}^\infty\frac{1}{(2j-1)^2-(2k-1)^2} =
\frac{-1}{4(2j-1)^2}
$$
These may be computed with information about the "digamma" function $\psi(z) = \Gamma'(z)/\Gamma(z)$, namely:
$$
\sum_{k=u}^v \frac{1}{a+k} = \psi(a+v+1)-\psi(a+u),
\qquad\text{where }u<v\text{ integers and } a\text{ complex}
$$
and
$$
\psi(z) = \log z -\frac{1}{2z} + O\left(\frac{1}{z^2}\right)\text{ as } z \to +\infty
$$